# Vim looks different in tmux

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I am trying to figure what could be wrong with pantheon, but for some reason it does not like tmux. Below on the left is what I am getting and on the right is what it should look like. I started tmux with `tmux -2`

[image]

I have downloaded another terminal `terminator` and it looks just fine

[image]

[My dotfiles can be found here.](https://github.com/jrock2004/dotfiles) Thanks for any help